# Generating Client code using svcutil

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I am trying to generate client proxy code using svcutil.exe tool. And its throwing follwong error.

I am using following command.

svcutil /namespace:http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5,* /out:STARContract.cs /noConfig SendOrderOrder.wsdl SendOrderOrderType.xsd

--------------------Output ----------------------

Error: There was an error verifying some XML Schemas generated during export:
The 'http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5:SendOrder' element is not declared.

Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Descripti
on.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: The element 'http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5:SendOrder' is missing.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservices
/2005/10/transport/bindings']/wsdl:portType[@name='starTransportPortTypes']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservice
s/2005/10/transport/bindings']/wsdl:portType[@name='starTransportPortTypes']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservices
/2005/10/transport/bindings']/wsdl:binding[@name='starTransport']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservices
/2005/10/transport/bindings']/wsdl:binding[@name='starTransport']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.starstandards.org/webservices
/2005/10/transport/bindings']/wsdl:service[@name='SendOrderWebService']/wsdl:port[@name='SendOrderStarTransport']

Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents did not contai
n any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. Verify that you
 passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to use the /dataContrac
tOnly option.

--------- End of output -----------------

The relative file references looks fine.

When I try to create same code using WSE it works fine and generate relate proxy class without any errors. However it does not work when using svcutil.exe.

Any idea?

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with WSDL/XSDs you are referring to so I can't explain the specifics of why this is failing.

However, in my view, the code generation aspects of the .Net wsdl and xsd tools have been broken for a long time. They do not cope with many standard industry conventions (including handling AttributeGroup constructs, coercing of namespaces on includes, poor handling of nillable elements, and the list goes on.

If your WSDL/XSD files use import and/or include statements .Net is probably going to choke. I have had a number of occasions where tools like SOAPUI correctly handle the WSDL and can generate various artifacts but .Net is unable to cope.

Some people have had some success with a tool called [WSCF Blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) but unfortunately I have generally flattened/tidied the WSDL/XSD file by hand until .Net can cope with it.

Comment: -1: this doesn't answer the question, and in fact is more of a rant than a response.

Comment: No, svcutil definitely works with import & include statements. In fact the framework uses these when generating `wsdl` files.

Comment: It was intended to be an answer. I was intending to point the OP to known issues with these tools so if his schemas have these characteristics he is clear it is likely to be a very difficult road. 

I have wasted countless days massaging WSDL/XSD files to workaround these issues. On most occasions I should have just used other tools or hand-coded from the outset.

For a small glimpse of the nightmare google "svcutil opentravel". These tools work great on .Net generated schemas but aren't commercial grade if you're doing serious interop.

Comment: I am not an expert on WSDL/XSD but I have seen this faling many times. Even when I used WSE to generate the proxy and then try to consume that proxy it didnt worked. I have tried the WSCF Blue and it did worked but becouse svcutil.exe didnt worked for what ever reason it didnt gave me enough confidence to use it. 'Kirk', unfortunately the schema (WSDL and XSD) as too large for me to perfom every import check manually(inshort time) (unless there are any tools avail which I am not aware of). I guess I have ask for more generic version of wsdl. Thanks